# Is it possible to access mysql database with android app on a laptop via bluetooth?

Tags: android, mysql, bluetooth

Suppose I am developing an android app that performs login and register functionalities. Now I  want to test it through mobile device (running app on mobile and trying to access the xampp server database from mobile via bluetooth, storing new users profiles and retrieving old ones) so just for information purpose I want to ask if it is possible, if so then tell me in a short description that how we can do this.